# Python mypy: float and int are incompatible types with numbers.Real

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I am new to Python's static typing module `mypy`. I am trying to append ints and floats to an array, which I typed statically to be Real. But `mypy` says that they are incompatible types with Real. I thought ints and floats are a subtype of Real?

```
from typing import List
from numbers import Real

data : List[Real] = []
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        if subject == 'time':
            data.append(float(line))
        else:
            data.append(int(line))
```

Error message:

```sh
graph.py:56: error: Argument 1 to "append" of "list" has incompatible type "float"; expected "Real"
graph.py:58: error: Argument 1 to "append" of "list" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Real"
```

Comment: Please see [pep-0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower), it recommends just using `float` for the type hint.

Answer (score 1):

As `AChampion` says you can just use `float` in place of `numbers.Real`. Pep 0484 (specifically [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower)) basically says that in the context of type-checking the hierarchy `complex > float > int` is respected and that `numbers.*` doesn't need to be used.

This is a known 'issue' with mypy and was raised and discussed [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186). I haven't read the entire discussion but the tldr seems to be that Pep 0484 is enough to make this a low priority issue (and it hasn't been resolved in 5 years).

I will say that (as the issue discussion mentioned) it would be nice if `mypy` gave some indication of this as a known issue in it's error message, which it currently (`mypy 0.991`) doesn't.