# A builtin python type to represent real numbers

Tags: python, python-typing

I'd like a builtin type that doesn't require the `numpy` dependency, but will allow me to express the fact that a variable is a real number. That is, an integer, a float, builtin or any of the fancy `numpy` ones (`numpy.int16`, `numpy.float32`, etc.).

Now, `numbers.Real` is almost right since instance and subclass checks work:

```py
from numbers import Real

assert isinstance(10.0, Real)
assert issubclass(type(10.0), Real)
assert isinstance(np.int16(4), Real)
assert not isinstance(2 + 3j, Real)
```

Yet the following code:

```py
import random
import numbers


def foo(x: numbers.Real, y: numbers.Real):
    return random.uniform(x, y)
```

makes the linter complain that `Expected type 'float', got 'Real' instead`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63894187/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50928592/3001761

Comment: It looks like [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower) says to just use `float` for the type hinting.